# Change color of PDF annotations with iText

Tags: java, pdf, itext

I want to change the color of all my highlighting annotations of my PDF. There is the function `com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation.setColor(BaseColor color)`, how can I call this function? Below is the code to iterate through all highlight annotations.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {

    try {

        // Reads and parses a PDF document
        PdfReader reader = new PdfReader("Test.pdf");

        // For each PDF page
        for (int i = 1; i <= reader.getNumberOfPages(); i++) {

            // Get a page a PDF page
            PdfDictionary page = reader.getPageN(i);
            // Get all the annotations of page i
            PdfArray annotsArray = page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS);

            // If page does not have annotations
            if (page.getAsArray(PdfName.ANNOTS) == null) {
                continue;
            }

            // For each annotation
            for (int j = 0; j < annotsArray.size(); ++j) {

                // For current annotation
                PdfDictionary curAnnot = annotsArray.getAsDict(j);

                if (PdfName.HIGHLIGHT.equals(curAnnot.get(PdfName.SUBTYPE))) {

                    //how to access com.itextpdf.text.pdf.PdfAnnotation.setColor(BaseColor color)

                }
            }
        }

    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately the iText `PdfAnnotation` class is only for *creating new annotations* from scratch, it is *not a wrapper for pre-existing ones*.

Thus, you essentially have to manipulate your `PdfDictionary curAnnot` with lowlevel methods like

```
curAnnot.put(PdfName.C, new PdfArray(new float[]{1, 0, 0}));
```

This entry for the name **C** is specified as

> **C** array *(Optional; PDF 1.1)* An array of numbers in the range 0.0 to 1.0,
>   representing a colour used for the following purposes:
>
> The background of the annotation’s icon when closed
>
> The title bar of the annotation’s pop-up window
>
> The border of a link annotation
>
> The number of array elements determines the colour space in which the
>   colour shall be defined:
>
> 0 No colour; transparent
>
> 1 **DeviceGray**
>
> 3 **DeviceRGB**
>
> 4 **DeviceCMYK**
>
> *(Table 164 – Entries common to all annotation dictionaries – [ISO 32000-1](http://www.adobe.com/content/dam/Adobe/en/devnet/acrobat/pdfs/PDF32000_2008.pdf))*

PS: Don't forget to eventually store the changes using something like

```
new PdfStamper(reader, new FileOutputStream("changed.pdf")).close();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
PdfAnnotation annotation = new PdfAnnotation(your_pdf_writer, new Rectangle(your_rectangle_information_here));
annotation.setColor(your_color_here);
```

You will also need a PdfWriter to write to your pdf and the information about the rectangle that you are drawing on the PDF.

Hope this helps!

Reference: [creating anootations itext](http://what-when-how.com/itext-5/creating-annotations-itext-5/)

Comment: This is adding only an annotation, isn't it. However, I want to change the colour of all existing annotations.